# Function to create n child processes

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, parent-child

```
int proc_create(int n)
{
   int pid;
   n = n+1;
   printf("The parent process id: %d\n", getpid());
   while(1)
   {
      if(pid=fork() < 0){
         perror("Fork Failed!");
         exit(1);
      }else{
         printf("The child process ID is: %d\n", pid);
      }
   }
}
```

I have written the above function that will create n child processes and each child processes will print out it's own child id. Can someone tell me the flaws and how i can improve the above function.

Comment: When is it supposed to stop spawning children?

Comment: Your while will loop indefinitely. It should loop `n` times.

Comment: Your code runs an infinite loop. I would not deploy it on a shared machine as you may very quickly crash it. What you have written is a typical fork bomb.

Comment: `fork()` returns 0 in child, child pid in parent and -1 on failure. You need to fix your condition checks.

Comment: Note how the behavior differs when you redirect output to a file rather than a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

`n` is a local variable, so you just do n + 1 which doesn't change anything.

It creates infinite child processes, because the fork is inside a `while(1)` loop

```
int *proc_create(int n) {
    int *childs = malloc(sizeof *childs * n);

    printf("The parent process id: %d\n", getpid());
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) {
            perror("Fork Failed!");
            exit(1);
        } else if (pid == 0) {
            return NULL;
        } else {
            childs[i] = pid;
            printf("The child process ID is: %d\n", pid);
        }
    }

    return childs;
}
```

This process spawn N children, when they return from `proc_create()` they will return `NULL`. The parent will return an array with the pids of its N children.